How to make the autograd to propagate through the parameter replacement?
I am trying to do a meta learning for CIFAR 10 using a VanillaCNN function that I wrote.

take the gradient of the CNN as input to LSTM
LSTM outputs the CNN weights
Based on the CNN parameter, I refit the size and replace the CNN parameters with the LSTM output.
I calculate the loss with the CNN (the one with new parameters)
backpropagate -> I do not do optimizer.step() on the CNN, bc the weights are supposed to be changing based on the LSTM output, so I try to back step the LSTM meta learner only.

# start off with the validation definition and then add the LSTM factor. 
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torchvision import datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


def accuracy(outputs, labels):
    # model output is the size of batch x label
    # get the labels from the outputs. 
    batch_size = outputs.shape[0]
    val, idx = torch.max(outputs, dim = -1)
    correct = idx.eq(labels).sum() * 1.0
    acc = correct / batch_size
    return acc

class VanillaCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VanillaCNN, self).__init__()
        #############################################################################
        # TODO: Initialize the Vanilla CNN                                          #
        #       Conv: 7x7 kernel, stride 1 and no padding                           #
        #       Max Pooling: 2x2 kernel, stride 2                                   #
        #############################################################################
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_feed_size = None
        self.cnn_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 7, stride = 1, padding = 0),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2),
            )
        self.linear = nn.Linear(5408,10)

        #############################################################################
        #                              END OF YOUR CODE                             #
        #############################################################################

    def forward(self, x):
        outs = None
        #############################################################################
        # TODO: Implement forward pass of the network                               #
        #############################################################################
        out_before_linear = self.cnn_stack(x)
        flat_out_before_linear = self.flatten(out_before_linear)
        #self.linear_feed_size = flat_out_before_linear.shape[-1]
        #self.linear = nn.Linear(self.linear_feed_size,10)
        outs = self.linear(flat_out_before_linear)
        
        # the final product has to be 128 x 10
        #############################################################################
        #                              END OF YOUR CODE                             #
        #############################################################################

        return outs

training_data = datasets.CIFAR10(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

test_data = datasets.CIFAR10(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)



batch_size = 128
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
  


########################## Define the initialialization ##########################
##################################################################################
# define the vision model 
vision_model = VanillaCNN()
# get the total number of the vision_model to initialize the LSTM model
total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in vision_model.parameters())
# print the number of total_params
print(f'the total parameter amount of the CNN is {total_params}')

# initialize the LSTM_meta learning + the initial LSTM input
LSTM_hidden = 64
LSTM_input = 64

h = torch.randn(1,LSTM_hidden)
c = torch.randn(1,LSTM_hidden)
# move to cuda. 
h = h.cuda()
c = c.cuda()

class LSTM_Meta(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, lstm_input_dim, lstm_hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(LSTM_Meta, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, lstm_input_dim)  # Reduce input dimension to LSTM input
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(lstm_input_dim, lstm_hidden_dim)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(lstm_hidden_dim, output_dim)  # Expand LSTM hidden dimension to original size

    def forward(self, x, h, c):
        x = self.linear1(x)  # Dimensionality reduction
        x, (h, c) = self.lstm(x, (h, c))  # LSTM processing with hidden and cell states
        x = self.linear2(x)  # Expand back to original dimension
        return x, (h, c)  # Return the output and the new hidden and cell states

# initiliaze the optimizer
LSTM_meta_learner = LSTM_Meta(total_params, LSTM_input, LSTM_hidden, total_params)
meta_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(LSTM_meta_learner.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
# initilize the loss function . 
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
######################## Finish the initialization ##############################
#################################################################################



######################## Start the trainining loops #############################
#################################################################################
epochs = 5
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f'current epoch is {epoch}')
    for idx, (features, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        
        # move the features and labels to cuda
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            features = features.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
            LSTM_meta_learner = LSTM_meta_learner.cuda()
            vision_model = vision_model.cuda()
            
        # get the gradient of the vision model
        gradient_list = []
        for name, param in vision_model.named_parameters():
            if param.grad is not None:
                gradient_list.append(param.grad.view(-1,1))
                
        # if the length of the gradient_list is bigger than 0, then try the concat
        # because without the length > 0, pytorch cannot concat. 
        if len(gradient_list) > 0:
            gradient_tensor = torch.cat(gradient_list).cuda()
            gradient_tensor = torch.transpose(gradient_tensor,0,1)
            # then if the gradient tensor length matches the total parameter
            if gradient_tensor.size()[1] == total_params:
                
                # run the gradient_tensor through the LSTM 
                weight_output, (h,c) = LSTM_meta_learner(gradient_tensor, h, c)
                # see if the LSTM_meta_learner parameter are getting updated. 
                i = 0
                LSTM_param_sum = 0
                for name, param in LSTM_meta_learner.named_parameters():
                    if param is not None:
                        LSTM_param_sum += torch.sum(param.view(-1,1))
                        if i == 5:
                            break
                print(f'the LSTM_meta_learner parameter sum is {LSTM_param_sum}')
                
                
                
                for name, param in vision_model.named_parameters():
                    param_shape = param.size()
                    param_size = torch.prod(torch.tensor(param_shape))
                    param_weights = weight_output[0,0:param_size]
                    weight_output = weight_output[:,param_size::]
                    
                    # need to reshape the weight_output to the param_weights
                    param_weights = torch.reshape(param_weights, param_shape)
                    param.data = param_weights
        
            # get the output of the model 
        output = vision_model(features)
        loss = loss_fn(output, labels)
        if idx % 10 == 0:
            print(f'the loss of the the training batch is {loss}')
        loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
        
        #################### create the loss for the LSTM ######################
        ########################################################################
        
        meta_optimizer.step()
        meta_optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # clear the list for the cuda memory control 
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        torch.cuda.reset_max_memory_allocated()
        del gradient_list
        if 'gradient_tensor' in globals():
            del gradient_tensor
        del features
        del labels
############################ finish the trainining loop ##########################
##################################################################################


########################### start the validation loop ############################
##################################################################################

    valid_batch_acc_list = []
    for idx_val, (valid_features, valid_labels) in enumerate(test_dataloader):
        # move the features and labels to cuda
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            valid_features = valid_features.cuda()
            valid_labels = valid_labels.cuda()
            vision_model = vision_model.cuda()
        # ready the model for the evaluation
        vision_model.eval()
        
        
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = vision_model(valid_features)
        # able to assume that outputs and labels are in the cuda space
        valid_batch_acc = accuracy(outputs, valid_labels)
        if idx_val % 100 == 0:
            print(f'valid accuracy is {valid_batch_acc}')
        valid_batch_acc_list.append(valid_batch_acc)
        
    epoch_valid_acc = torch.mean(torch.tensor(valid_batch_acc_list))
    print(f'the valid epoch acc is {epoch_valid_acc}')

The issue is that the LSTM_meta_learner parameters do not change. I somewhat expected this because I think autograd cannot handle the parameters replacing and back track that.
How can I make the gradient propagate all the way to the LSTM meta learner?
